# Enabling empty selection on view-based NSTableViews

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I've setup a view-based NSTableView using bindings and everything is working accordingly. However, I'm having issues when it comes to empty selections. I've bound my NSTableView's Content and SelectionIndexes to an NSArrayController and ensured that both the NSTableView and the NSArrayController allow empty selections. In fact, I know this to be true because when I manually pass an empty NSIndexSet to my NSArrayController's setSelectionIndexes: method my NSTableView correctly deselects all of its rows.

The issue I'm having is getting my NSTableView to deselect when the user clicks the empy space beneath the NSTableView's populated rows. I'm fairly certain this is default behaviour, but I can't for the life of me find a way to make my NSTableView behave this way.

Answer (score 0):

you can certainly use this :

```
[myTableView deselectAll:self];
```

where myTableView is your NSTableView.